# Angular: How to use multiple For loops in a table?

Tags: angular

In my database, data format is like this for every user

```
Array=[
 {
  id:4,
  name:"john", 
  product:[
   {productname:"mobile",id:1},
   {productname:"airconditioners",id:2}
   ]
 },
 {
  id:5,
  name:"Brayden", 
  product:[
   {productname:"coolers",id:1}, 
   {productname:"Lights",id:2}
   ]
  }
 ]
```

This data I am displaying in table using edit and delete buttons. When I click on edit button I am showing that user `id` in alert. But when I click on delete button I want to show `id` and `productname`.

Suppose if I click delete button for user "John." I want to show `id:4, productname:[{mobile,airconditioners}]`.

[StackBlitz: Display data in table using array of objects in](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngkry4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I tried to use one more for-loop using ng-container for displaying `productname`, but data displays twice.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Instead of passing id to the delete function just pass in the object. Then you can play around with that object. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1excv

Comment: I tried what you says----Delete(user){
const obj=user.product.map(user=>user.productname)  
alert(JSON.stringify(user.product))
}. It shows id also. I need only productname like [{productname:"mobile",productname:"airconditioners"}] I tried to split id's but still id's are showing.

Comment: Well you're doing `alert(JSON.stringify(user.product)) }` is not the same as `alert(JSON.stringify(obj)) }`

Comment: Yes, It is not same But it gives like ['mobiles','airconditioners']. I am expecting this [{productname:"mobile",productname:"airconditioners"}]

Comment: Then you would just reconfigure your map to return an object. Have a look at how [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) works